# Optimal DateTime Converter for all cultures

Tags: wpf, silverlight, datetime, converters

I am about to create a Converter to translate the date into a custom format.

In fact in one converter I have a date like this 17/05/2011 00:00:00 that I would like to convert to simply 17/05/2011.  However the culture shall be also taken into consideration.

In my example above I had the British culture, but if the user is American then it shall be converted into 05/17/2011.

Effectively I would also need a ConvertBack to convert the date back regardless of the culture into a Database friendly format to save it back universally and safe without misunderstanding.

This was my first try which already fails:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(value == null)
                return null;

            DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString(), culture);

            return date;
        }
```

Also surprising is that the CultureInfo parameter above is Us-en, despite everything in Windows is set to United Kingdom.  Btw I am using this converter for Silverlight 4, perhaps obtaining the culture is different here... None the less weird enough I get an expection 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' I think this is due the American culture I have there that doesn't understand 17 as a month.  How do I set my local culture in a silverlight app?

And then I would need a second converter to return only the time similar to above.  i figured I might be able to use the overload DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault for it to generate only time from dates, correct?

Many Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

Setting a culture can be done on the current thread, each thread in an application can be in a different culture.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture(v=VS.100).aspx

Curious, if your computer is in en-gb but your application is in en-us, I would surmise the application is being put into that culture explicitly, perhaps by the configuration file.  If the application is not given a culture, it takes the OS culture.

In ASP.NET web apps I remember you could also specify culture in the config file.

Is your end goal just to cut off the time portion of the `DateTime`?  If so, there is a `DateTime.Date` property available and you could then convert using the default .NET culture support.

The `ConvertBack` method could save the time as UTC, there are various methods on a `DateTime` for saving to UTC.  UTC includes time zone information and comes in one format, good for databases.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx

Though to be honest, if SQL Server is your database server, so long as you store dates as dates and not strings, again culture is taken care of for you.

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for your response. I have tried date.Date, however the time at the end is still there and not being cut off. 17/05/2011 00:00:00 I could onbviously use a substring and cut it myself, but I wished using a cleaner way of retrieving date without the time.

Comment: And regarding the culture, I have checked the App.config and Web.config and couldnt find anywhere the culture set to US. In fact EF4 has set Culture=neutral for its services. Still investigating this...

Comment: If you want to get the date to a string, then you can use `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString`.  This conforms to locale.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I am still struggeling getting the culture right. The culture is still set to US. How can I make it read my PC's culture? I would like to have it this way, that any user from anywhere in the world would see the local familiar format for dates and time. I dont want to enforce one or other way. You know what I mean?

Comment: @Kave hi, I'm not really sure why it keeps choosing a different culture for you.  My guess is it's configured somewhere without you realising.  Your best bet is to post a question with just that and you should get some fast responses.